# java.lang.NumberFormatException: Infinite or NaN at java.math.BigDecimal

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have the following code

```
double a = 29.0;
double b = 9.0;
double c = 4.0;
BigDecimal sum= new BigDecimal(0.0);
sum=sum.add(new BigDecimal(Math.log10((a)/(b*c) /Math.log10(2)));
```

I tried to use double for sum instead of BigDecimal but it gives me infinity as a result. when I used BigDecimal I got no results but error says:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: Infinite or NaN
>       at java.math.BigDecimal.(Unknown Source)

any help please cause this is the first time I deal with large numbers
Note: a, b, anc c values will be changed through a loop and because of that I have to save the total sum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>`(a)/(b*c) /Math.log10(2)` is negative, so taking the log of that gives `NaN`.</s> **Actually, that's nonsense, it's not negative.  I don't know why you'd be getting an exception there.**

It looks like you're really just trying to do log<sub>2</sub>, in which case you've just put your parentheses in the wrong place,

Comment: So, my problem is in the parentheses. thanks a lot I am trying now to see if it works. (my program takes time for every run)